# Google analytics does not work on android 4.0

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova, google-analytics

Google analytics does not work on android 4.0+

Hi there,

I built a mobile application for Iphone ,Android and Blackberry using html5, CSS3 and 
Jquery mobile with Phonegap.
I applyed Google Analytics on the app and on iOS and Android 2.0+ is working ok, but on Android 4.0+ is not working at all.
I tried different codes, Universal analytics.js and ga.js but it wasn't succes.
I am trying even some example codes on Android and even a plain html page with Analytics packing with Phonegap doesn't work.
Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-00000000-1', {
        'storage': 'none',
        'clientId': '92bf24a5-20e5-4181-9778-2835f28c52d8'
    });
    ga('send', 'pageview', { 'page': 'index' });

</script>
```

or this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
```

But it is not working on Android 4.0+... where am I doing wrong, maybe some setting on Google analytics? Thanks...

Comment: 1. UA-xxxxxxxx-1 or UA-00000000-1 need to be your GA property ID.
2. You have to send calls like _trackPageview().

Comment: Yes, I am adding my Ga account, just don't want make public my GA, I am gonna try to use _trackPageview(), thanks Alison ;)

Comment: Since you're using the javascript in an app instead of the SDK, I - personally - would look into Phonegap issues before GA issues. It wouldn't let me add the phonegap tag to this question, but maybe you can?